# storageRef.downloadURL isn't executing code inside

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("user/\(uid)")

    let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)

    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    storageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData)
    //Get url
    let imageRef = storageRef
    imageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }else{
            print(url.absoluteString)
        }
    }

}
```

The code inside will not execute, it will skip everything and act like there is no code stored. I am unsure how completions work but I would imagine it would either print the error or print the url but it does neither. When I set a breakpoint here it doesn't even bother checking if error = error. Is there something I did wrong or anyone else having the same problem?

```
imageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }else{
        print(url.absoluteString)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your **putData:metadata:completion:** doesn't have completion block. have a look here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files

Answer (score 0):

Your **putData:metadata:completion:** doesn't have completion block. You can access to download URL **after** upload so putData should be look like this.

```
storageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in
            guard let metadata = metadata else {
                // an error occurred!
                return
            }
            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
            let size = metadata.size

            // You can only access to download URL after upload.
            let imageRef = storageRef

            imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                    // an error occurred!
                    return
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it then skips all the code inside of this completion block

Comment: @Cristian API call is asynchronous so you need to set a breakpoint inside completion block

Answer (score 0):

Your API call is asynchronic so that why you need instead of print actually use completion block to return the result (error or value).

Comment: How would I do this? Sorry I am new to this